# Grouping SSRS results by cell background color

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have created a report in SSRS which shows Disk information on multiple servers, and it is set so that background cells turn orange if free space is under 20% and red if under 10%. I would like to have the RED cells (critical disks needing cleaning) at the top of the report.

Is there a group expression I can make to achieve this (grouping by back ground color or % < 10)? I couldn't figure it out. 
No questions on this online either from what I have seen

Thanks!

Comment: Why not order the report by % free disk space ascending?

Comment: Can't believe I never though of that. Such a simple solution. Thanks. Post that as answer and I will accept it!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply order by the percentage of free disk space ascending.

*Putting this as an answer as I genuinely think this is it!*